# Django doesn't load new files from static directory until server restarted

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django app in production which have the functionality to save the images to the `app/static/gallery/` directory from the app.

then application loads those images from the directory in the template.

```
<img src="{% static 'gallery/1.jpg' %}">
```

- Problem here is as the application is in production & constantly saves the images under `static/gallery` it won't load new images until I restarted the server.

I'm using `http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html#` to serve static files.

```
→ django-admin version
2.2.4
```

- How to tackle this problem to always serve static files to load them instantly without restarting the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what the static part of django is for.

Unsurprisingly it's static content that gets pulled in to `STATIC_ROOT` and then served via `STATIC_URL`. This happens when you run `manage.py collectstatic`, usually part of starting the server. To do what you're talking about, you'd have to run this command every time you add an image to the static path.

If you're allowing the application/users to upload content then you need to make use of the media side of django (opposed to static). The main settings which are used for this, as an example of a project I've got open are;

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

To upload content like this you typically have a model field which might look like;

```
def uuid():
    """ Generate a UUID """
    return urlsafe_b64encode(uuid4().bytes).decode("ascii").rstrip("=")


def upload_path(instance, filename):
    """ Upload to path with UUID """
    return "gallery/{uuid}/{file}".format(uuid=uuid(), file=filename)


class Gallery(models.Model):

    image = models.FileField(
        upload_to=upload_path,
    )
```

A `FileField` then provides a `url` attribute that you can use in your templates;

```
<img src="{{ obj.image.url }}" />
```

Further reading on handling files is here; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/files/